# How to make this work in all other browsers other than Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a select list with numbers in it. These numbers go from 0 to 30. I want to hide numbers based on the number of days apart from the current date and the date the user set.

So if today is July 28th 2010 and they Set July 29th 2010 it should only show "0".

If it was July 28th 2010 and they set September 20th 2010 it should show 0 to 30.

So I have this

```
  var selectedDate = new Date($('#TextBox').val().replace(/\/(\d\d)$/, "/20$1"));
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

    currentDate = new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);


    if (isNaN(selectedDate) == false)
    {
        $('#selectList').find('select').attr('disabled', '');

        var diffDays = parseInt((selectedDate  - currentDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        var Options = $('#selectList').find('option');

        jQuery.each(Options, function (i, value)
        {
            var currentValue = $(this).val();
            if (currentValue == -1)
            {
                // equal to continue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (currentValue >= diffDays)
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

This code happens on change of the textbox of where the user would select a date.

This works fine in FireFox but does not work in any other browser. I don't know why. No errors are shown in any of the browsers.

Comment: have you tried `currentDate = new date(year, month-1, day);` ??

Comment: I’m not sure `isNaN()` works on Dates constructed using `new Date()`. It should definitely work on timestamps constructed using `Date.parse()`. After checking `isNaN()` on that, you can then create the date using `new Date(timestamp)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can't hide/show `<option>` elements like this cross-browser, you need to either have a backup/hidden `<select>` and copy only the `<option>` elements you want each time, or just disable the `<option>` elements you don't want to be selectable, this will however leave them visible.

The cloning bit would look something like this:

```
var hiddenSelect = $("#selectList").find('select').clone();
var selectedDate = new Date($('#TextBox').val().replace(/\/(\d\d)$/, "/20$1"));
var currentDate = new Date();

var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

currentDate = new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);


if (isNaN(selectedDate) == false) {
    $('#selectList').find('select').attr('disabled', '');
    var diffDays = parseInt((selectedDate  - currentDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    var select = $('#selectList').find('select').empty();
    hiddenSelect.children().each(function(i, value) {
        if (value == -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (currentValue < diffDays) {
            $(this).clone().appendTo(select);
        }      
    });
}
```

We're just keeping a cloned copy of the original in a variable called `hiddenSelect`, emptying (via [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)) out the options on the visible one in the UI,  and looping through/cloning the options you *want* to see back into that visible select.

Comment: Hmm interesting. How can I clone it if I had 5 selectLists(all 0 to 30), how would I do that one? Do I have to make a each loop around the hiddenSelect.children()

Comment: @chobo2 - If it's the same options (text/value) in each select, yes you can store a clone of any of them just once and loop through that same cloned `<select>` for each one you're populating.